# How to make a variadic lambda?

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, clang, variadic-functions

When I try to make a variadic lambda:

```
#include <cstdarg>

int main() {
    [] (int x, ...) { va_list xs; va_start(xs, x); va_end(xs); };
    return 0;
}
```

With GCC this compiles fine, but clang rejects it:

```
main.cpp:4:35: error: 'va_start' used in function with fixed args
    [] (int x, ...) { va_list xs; va_start(xs, x); va_end(xs); };
                                  ^
```

Which compiler is correct here? Is it possible to make a variadic lambda?

---

Curiously, the following results in an ICE with clang, so it looks like clang is being buggy with variadics:

```
int f(...) {
    [] (int x, ...) { va_list xs; va_start(xs, x); va_end(xs); };
    return;
}
```

Comment: Your original example works in Visual Studio 2013 as well.

Comment: "Which compiler is correct here?" Certainly not the one that ICEs.

Comment: @Griwes and the standard says....?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Variadic lambdas seem to be allowed - the syntax to specify the parameters is the same *parameter-declaration-clause* used by any other function declaration, and there's no specific rule to disallow it from ending with an ellipsis. (C++11 does ban default arguments, but not ellipses, and that restriction was removed in C++14.)

In any case, if there's an internal compiler error (which I assume is what you mean by ICE), then that means the compiler has a bug, regardless of the correctness of the code.